# Unable to use Scrapy item as data for MySQL.execute: "Wrong number of arguments during string formatting"

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, mysql-connector-python

I'm using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to parse content from a website into [Items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Item), which replicate the `dict` API:

```
import scrapy

class ScheduleItem(scrapy.Item):
    flight = scrapy.Field()
```

I'm trying to use the Item above directly as the data for a Connector/Python [`MySQLCursor.execute()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) statement using pyformat-style values.  However, it's falling over with the following error:

```
(Pdb) add_schedule_sql()
'INSERT INTO schedules (flight) VALUES (%(flight)s)'

(Pdb) foo = items.ScheduleItem();
(Pdb) foo['flight'] = 'abc'
(Pdb) foo.keys()
['flight']
(Pdb) print foo
{'flight': 'abc'}
(Pdb) self.cursor.execute(add_schedule_sql(), foo)
*** ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting
```

There's exactly one value to insert and exactly one value in the Item, both with the same key, so I'm rather baffled by this error.  ([Source code here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~geertjmvdk/myconnpy/main/annotate/head%3A/python2/mysql/connector/cursor.py#L308), which indicates it's actually hiding a TypeError.)  If I use a plain old dict, it works fine:

```
(Pdb) bar = {'flight': 'abc'}
(Pdb) bar.keys()
['flight']
(Pdb) self.cursor.execute(add_schedule_sql(), bar)
(Pdb)
```

And if I map the item into a dict, the call also works fine:

```
(Pdb) self.cursor.execute(add_schedule_sql(), dict(item))
(Pdb)
```

The above is simple enough that it actually solves my problem adequately, but I'm still curious about what's wrong with just using an Item.  Python 2.7.5, Scrapy 0.24 (latest stable).

Comment: Judging [from this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#topics-items-declaring) you must have special source for `ScheduleItem` that allows flight as a field. If that also has other fields, they might be visible in terms of `Items` "dict-like" interface. Even if they are empty, maybe internally scrapy stores them with a `None` value or something, and it merely doesn't print them as part of the `repr` unless the user has explicitly set them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. So we need to see your implementation of `ScheduleItem` and also we need the version numbers of the libraries involved.

```
In [10]: class ScheduleItem(scrapy.Item):
flight = scrapy.Field()
delay = scrapy.Field()
....:     

In [11]: foo = ScheduleItem()

In [12]: foo['flight'] = 'abc'

In [13]: foo
Out[13]: {'flight': 'abc'}

In [14]: "test %(flight)s str"%(foo)
Out[14]: 'test abc str'

In [15]: "test (flight) and %(flight)s str"%(foo)
Out[15]: 'test (flight) and abc str'
```

Comment: Your code works for me too.  I don't think it's an issue with string interpolation as such, but something deeper in MySQLCursor.execute.

Comment: At the MySQL link you give, there is a comment at the bottom about the way that the function consumes dict params only once. Could it be confused by your use of `(flight)` before the `%(flight)s`? Maybe get rid of that first reference to `(flight)` (as in, rename it, or rename the variable you pass to the string) and try again?

Comment: In fact, that comment suggests that what `execute` is doing is something akin to `stmt.replace(key, value, 1)` which will definitely find the first `flight` and replace it.

Comment: Part of the problem is that it looks convoluted to find the source for this. I don't want to futz around with installing it from scratch... do you know if they keep this at a github page or anything?

Comment: See edits above, it's not just the keys because the same statement works fine when you convert the Item to a dict.  Source is here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~geertjmvdk/myconnpy/main/annotate/head%3A/python2/mysql/connector/cursor.py#L308

Comment: Take a look at `_process_params` in that source file. It has a special function to process a `dict`, and otherwise it attempts to use `map` to spray certain type converter functions onto the iterable it was given, but that might not work on a `Item` object.